# How can I have no indent on \chapter*?

Tags: chapters, indentation, titlesec

For some reason, when I use `\chapter*` to have an unnumbered chapter, the chapter title is centered instead of having no indent like the normal `\chapter`...

I tried using the package `titlesec` and its command `\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]` to change the command `\chapter*`, using it like this: `\titleformat{\chapter*}[hang]{\bfseries\large\normalfont}{}{}{\noindent}[hang]`, but the program says `undefined control sequence` and it quotes the whole line in which I wrote that...

I just recently started using LaTeX and one template on it for a work of mine, but I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with that `\chapter*` centering problem because my work requires it to be like a normal chapter but without the numbering...

I'm new to the site, so I'm not sure what's the correct way of representing the code here, any help would be really appreaciated!

Comment: For default book class, `\chapter` is formatted using `\@makechapterhead` while `\chapter*` is formatted using `\@makeschapterhead`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the template you are using but for `report` or `book` classes, the chapter title is left aligned as default.

If you want to change alignment of the chapter title using the `titlesec` package, you can try an easier method by adding option to the package declaration:

```
\usepackage[raggedleft]{titlesec}
```

[image]

[image]

A few more options you can try are `raggedright` and `center`.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec} 

\title{Chapter Test}
\author{An author}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{An example chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter*{Another example chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```